# Выбрать все элементы которые есть в магазине 1 и 2

Tags: sql, база-данных

У меня есть таблица такого типа:

```
id | name   | shop | price |
 1 | Яблоко |  1   |   5   |
 2 | Яблоко |  2   |   15  |
 3 | Груша  |  1   |   8   |
 4 | Груша  |  2   |   12  |
 4 | Персик |  1   |   18  |
```

`name` - имя
`shop` - id магазина
`price` - цена

Мне нужно сделать sql запрос, что бы получить все что есть в магазине `1` и `2`.
В примере выше это будет `яблоко` и `груша`, без `персика`, потому что он есть только в магазине `1`. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Дополните ответ своими попытками, пожалуйста. Судя по рейтингу - не новичок уже ;-)

Comment: И да. В приведённой таблице последний id верный?

Comment: `select name from table group by name having count(distinct shop) = 2`

Comment: и добавить `where shop IN (1,2)`, если есть и другие магазины

Comment: @RustamAliev у меня не было даже мысли как сделать такую выборку из базы :)
Сделал я так: беру уникальные строки со столбцом `shop` и считаю их количество (тут их 2), беру все товары и перебиваю в цикле php где опять беру товары, но уже по их имени и если их количество = количеству магазинов значит всё ок, остальные выкидываю. Работает, но как вы поняли - плохо, поэтому вопрос я оставил открытым. Про `id` - там ошибка, это пример таблицы, у меня она чуть посложнее и больше столбцов, но сути это не меняет.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Гуглив про `having` из комментария я сделал вот такой вот запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `tovars` WHERE `name` IN (
    SELECT `name` FROM `tovars` GROUP BY `name` HAVING COUNT(`name`)=(
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `shop`) FROM `tovars`
    )
)
```

Может можно его сделать намного меньше, но я не знаю как, да и он работает вполне адекватно.
В первом `SELECT` подсчитывается количество магазинов, во втором берутся все `name` товаров, которые есть во всех магазинах, и в третьем уже окончательном берётся вся информация о товарах по `name` доставленных из второго `SELECT`.

Comment: а чего минусят то?  в целом тут взят коммент @Mike  к вопросу. в динамику подзапросом переделано число магазинов, и несколько криво прикручена выборка всех данных. Более уместен будет джойн подзароса группировки к основной таблице по имени товара. В целом, конечно, адекватнее именования вынести в отдельную таблицу и выбирать их id.

Answer (score 0):

1 вариант:

```
WITH t AS(
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'apple' AS name, 1 AS shop, 5 AS price
  UNION
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'apple' AS name, 2 AS shop, 15 AS price
  UNION
  SELECT 3 AS id, 'pear' AS name, 1 AS shop, 8 AS price
  UNION
  SELECT 4 AS id, 'pear' AS name, 2 AS shop, 12 AS price
  UNION
  SELECT 4 AS id, 'peach' AS name, 1 AS shop, 18 AS price
)
  SELECT t.name
    FROM t
   WHERE t.shop = 1
     AND t.name IN (SELECT name FROM t WHERE shop = 2)
```

2 вариант:

```
WITH t as (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'apple' AS name, 1 AS shop, 5 AS price
  UNION
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'apple' AS name, 2 AS shop, 15 AS price
  UNION
  SELECT 3 AS id, 'pear' AS name, 1 AS shop, 8 AS price
  UNION
  SELECT 4 AS id, 'pear' AS name, 2 AS shop, 12 AS price
  UNION
  SELECT 4 AS id, 'peach' AS name, 1 AS shop, 18 AS price
)
  SELECT t.name
    FROM t
   WHERE t.shop IN (1, 2)
   GROUP BY t.name
   HAVING COUNT(t.name) > 1
```

В чём разница между вариантами - тут уже **самостоятельно**...